# Routing from an IonCard to an iframe webpage

Tags: ionic-framework, react-router, ionic4, ionic-react

I've currently got an IonCard setup like this:

```
         <IonCard  routerLink={"/link/2"}>
            <IonCardContent>
              <IonCardSubtitle>Card Subtitle</IonCardSubtitle>
              <IonCardTitle>Card Title</IonCardTitle>
            </IonCardContent>

            <IonCardContent>
              Card Desc
            </IonCardContent>
          </IonCard>
```

and I'm trying to get the /2 bit to be recognised as an ID for the page at `/link/`

This page just loads in an iframe and I need to append the ID to the end of the src of that iframe.

The `link` page looks like this:

```
interface LinkProps extends RouteComponentProps<{
  id: string;
}> {}
```

In essence, I'm trying to get an ID in from the selection of a card to open a page with an iframe using that id as part of the URL for the iframe

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up the Router for the Parameter?

e.g.:
`<Route path="/xxx/:id" component={xxx}/>`